# Data-toggle fixing when routing in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, routes, nav

When I route in my ASP.net web app, the following toggle doesn't work

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center fixed" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="mainTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="hometab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true" style="font-size: 90%; text-align: center;">Home</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane container active" id="home" aria-labelledby="hometab" data-ride="tab"></div>
</div>
```

RouteConfig:

> routes.MapPageRoute( "ProfileRoute", "Profile/{userid}",
> "~/Profile.aspx" );

Url :

> Profile/id#home

How can i solve this problem ?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tabs navigation with custom routing in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62763305/tabs-navigation-with-custom-routing-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

*ActionLink* `@Html.ActionLink("Controller", "Action")`

```
  <a class="nav-link active" id="hometab" data-toggle="tab" style="font-size: 90%; text-align: center;">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index")</li>
        Home
    </a>
```

Or

```
  <a class="nav-link active" id="hometab" data-toggle="tab" href="@Url.Action("Controller", "Action", new {userid = ""})" style="font-size: 90%; text-align: center;">
       Home
    </a>
```

Comment: Okay thank you. But if I want to toggle a tab inside the same form using the actionlink you just mentioned, how can i do that?

Comment: do you mean scroll from one form to the next? I'm sorry if I didn't understand you correctly.

Comment: with Actionlink you can only go from page to page!

Comment: I updated my question - actually that's what I want to do in my updated question. I have a navigation bar and a navigation pane and the pane is on the same form. it used to work when , but since I changed the routing parameters into "Profile/{id}" and the {id} is fetched from the database, when I toggle this tab, it doesn't work and the URL turns to "Profile/{id}#home

Comment: define this  **name="home"**

Comment: define it in the tab-pane?

Comment: `<div class="tab-pane container active" name="home" id="home" aria-labelledby="hometab" data-ride="tab">`

Comment: nope. it didn't work.at first, my URL looked like Profile?user={id) and it used to toggle perfectly. It stopped working when I changed the route parameters to Profile/{id}

Comment: ```             routes.MapPageRoute(
                "ProfileRoute",
                "Profile/{userid}",
                "~/Profile.aspx"
                ); ``` This is how I defined my route parameters in routeconfig.cs

Comment: You can use somethin like this: `href="@Url.Action("Controller", "Action", new {userid = ""})`  but  i don't know how to get your **userid** I'm sorry :-

Comment: It's okay i don't have a problem with userid. But I just have a problem with the tabs thing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62763305/tabs-navigation-with-custom-routing-in-asp-net I specified my problem right here if you could help me out